# How do I figure out what process is blocking access to an IP address?

Tags: windows, process

One of my various installed programs is periodically blocking access to certain websites that (I think) it has falsely determined to be malicious. I'm having trouble figuring out which one is blocking connections to the IP addresses in question though.

Knowing that if I try to visit a given website the connection is flat out refused on the client side because of an intervening process, how can I determine which process blocked the request?

I'm using Windows 7 Professional, 64 bit.

Comment: Not entirely 100% sure so I won't write as an answer, but please let me know if it works and I will write it.... Take a look at Autoruns - technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx Especially the "Network Providers" and "Winsock Providers" tab to see programs that are listening.

Comment: I would first look at your Hosts file, that is the most common method that malicious software will use to block access to specific sites. You could also try a traceroute to that address just to be sure that it is stopping at your machine and not elsewhere. It would help to know what you are using to connect to that IP address (browser, ftp program, ssh, etc) as it might be a port issue and not something blocking an attempt at that IP.